# Duck typing to allow tuples, lists, or something that can be treated like one

Tags: python, duck-typing

```
def foo(spam, obj_of_interest):
"""Pass a _____ and an object of interest, and return [something that does something worthwhile] """
    name = spam[0]
    quest = spam[1]
    fav_color = spam[2]
    # ... interesting code
    return obj_of_interest
```

You'll note that `foo()` can function perfectly regardless of whether it's passed `spam` as a list, as a tuple, or really as anything that enforces an order to the element and can be addressed like a list.

How do you document this fact without telling the user to use a specific type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say,

```
"""spam is an object that supports indexing."""
```

Comment: Or more specifically, """spam is a sequence type""". A dictionary supports indexing, but may not be appropriate, as it is not ordered. (Ignoring dictionaries with the appropriate set of integer keys.)

Comment: The original asked for "anything that enforces an order to the element". Given the implementation of the function, one can see that a dictionary that simulates a sequence by having a subset of keys that comprise a continuous range of integers fits the criteria; but not every dictionary will.

Comment: Also, by being specific, you are free to change the implementation later with something like `name, quest, fav_color = spam` without the user being affected. An integer-keyed dictionary would not work with that change.